# SOAPUI Response to a file - each item to a new line

Tags: groovy, output, soapui, writetofile

I currently have a very simple script which returns all items within tag  and places them in an output file. The output is currently placing everything to one line (toString)
[88881028167, 88881028168, 88881028168, 88881028176, 88881028177, 88881028175, 88881028177, 88881028166, 88881028170]

I would like to change it so each item is on a new line and without the comma e.g.:
88881028167
88881028168
88881028176
etc

This is my current code

```
 import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
    def tl = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'TransmittalNumber'}
    new File('c:/temp/Input3.txt').write(tl.toString())
```

and it is searching through the previous case response  - sample below:

```
       <b:CommunicationResponse>
           <b:ActionDate i:nil="true"/>
           <b:AuditUser>XXXXXt</b:AuditUser>
           <b:CommunicationDirection>NOtoFO</b:CommunicationDirection>
           <b:CommunicationStatus>Acknowledged</b:CommunicationStatus>
           <b:CommunicationType>DSPC</b:CommunicationType>
           <b:ContactStatusDate>2018-03-15T17:18:12</b:ContactStatusDate>
           <b:Description>Test TL Report on 1 page width with decription</b:Description>
           <b:DueDate>2018-04-19T17:18:11</b:DueDate>
           <b:LogDate>2018-03-15T17:05:36</b:LogDate>
           <b:NOItemReference>987654321-_Digi_Test</b:NOItemReference>
           <b:NOPackingListNumber>PACK01</b:NOPackingListNumber>
           <b:ReferenceNumber>8888853</b:ReferenceNumber>
           <b:ResponseToReferenceNumber i:nil="true"/>
           <b:SCNumber>999202814</b:SCNumber>
           <b:SPNumber>786803</b:SPNumber>
           <b:TransmittalNumber>88881028167</b:TransmittalNumber>
           <b:UserGroup>NO</b:UserGroup>
        </b:CommunicationResponse>
        <b:CommunicationResponse>
           <b:ActionDate i:nil="true"/>
           <b:AuditUser>XXXXX</b:AuditUser>
           <b:CommunicationDirection>NOtoFO</b:CommunicationDirection>
           <b:CommunicationStatus>Acknowledged</b:CommunicationStatus>
           <b:CommunicationType>DSPC</b:CommunicationType>
           <b:ContactStatusDate>2018-03-15T17:10:19</b:ContactStatusDate>
           <b:Description/>
           <b:DueDate>2018-04-19T17:10:19</b:DueDate>
           <b:LogDate>2018-03-15T17:07:16</b:LogDate>
           <b:NOItemReference>987654351-_Digi_Test</b:NOItemReference>
           <b:NOPackingListNumber>PACK01</b:NOPackingListNumber>
           <b:ReferenceNumber>8888855</b:ReferenceNumber>
           <b:ResponseToReferenceNumber i:nil="true"/>
           <b:SCNumber>999202819</b:SCNumber>
           <b:SPNumber>786866</b:SPNumber>
           <b:TransmittalNumber>88881028168</b:TransmittalNumber>
           <b:UserGroup>NO</b:UserGroup>
        </b:CommunicationResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new File('c:/temp/Input3.txt').write(tl.toString())
```

To:

```
new File('c:/temp/Input3.txt').withWriter { w ->
    tl.each {
        w.writeLine it.text()
    }
}
```